# how to handle multiple ordered pairs in Event-B

Tags: event-b

I want to get the last two mapped elements of a deterministic ternary ordered pair in the form of binary ordered pairs, here's an example:
`set A = { 1 ↦  2 ↦ 3,1 ↦   5 ↦   6}` ，I want to get `set B = {2 ↦ 3, 5 ↦   6}` ，what should I do?
BTW:Is that possible?

I tried to get the domain and range of `set A` and use Cartesian product to get what I want,but I failed,the result set was disordered

Answer (score 0):

`A={ 1↦2↦3, 1↦5↦6}` is the same as `A={ (1↦2)↦3, (1↦5)↦6 }`, so you have a set of pairs here.

What you want is a combination of the left and right side of each entry, so domain and range won't work here. But you can achieve it with a set comprehension:

```
B = {a,b,c · a↦b↦c∈A ∣ b↦c}
```

(Read: For all triples a↦b↦c store b↦c in B)

But what do you mean by "disordered"? Since A and B are sets, there is no defined order. It does not make a difference whether it is `{2↦3, 5↦6}` or `{5↦6, 2↦3}`.

Comment: It works , thanks a lot :)